# How to watch deep array using computed in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a component like below in Vuejs.
But my goal is I want to get the value inside of filterdShoes of watch.

```
   data():{
       coor: [
              { "name": '',
                "shoes": '' },
              { "name": '',
                "shoes": '' }       
             ]
   },

   computed {
      filteredAny(){
        return this.coor.filter(it=>['shoes','name'].includes(it));
      },
      filteredShoes(){
        return this.coor.filter(it=>it === 'shoes');
      },
     filteredName(){
        return this.coor.filter(it=>it === 'name');
      }

    }

    watch {
      filteredShoes(){
        console.log('The shoes are changed');
      }

    }
```

So I tried like below.But it  says val is undefined.
I hope that 'val' is defined as 'coor' of data.
How can I fix this code? Thank you so much for reading this.

```
 watch {
      filteredShoes(val){  
        for(let i=0; i < val.length; i+=1){} 
      }

    }
```

Comment: You're hoping that 'val' of the watcher filteredShoes will be the filtered array from the computed prop filteredShoes?

Comment: yes.I want it. Kyuriko

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `this.coor` is an array of objects, `it` will be an object. Thus `it != 'shoes'`, and your filter will return an empty array.

Assuming you are using computed `filteredShoes()` like this:

```html
<div v-for="shoe in filteredShoes"> ... </div>
```

Then you can just use the computed property, no need for the watcher. *Everytime elements are added to/removed from the array,* the computed prop will run. **The computed property will not run if the properties of an object in the array are changed.**

Also, I'm not quite sure why your `this.coor` has such a structure, so I'm using this:

```js
coor: [
   { "name": 'Model 1', "shoes": 'Nike' },
   { "name": 'Model 2', "shoes": 'Reebok' }       
]
...
computed {
   filteredShoes(){
      let shoes = this.coor.filter(item => item.shoes === 'Nike');

      for(let i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++){ ... } // assuming you're modifying each object here

      return shoes; // return an array to be looped in HTML
   },
}
```

**If you're trying to filter by type**, I would recommend changing your `coor` to the following structure:

```js
coor: [
   { "name": 'Model 1', "type": 'shoe' },
   { "name": 'Model 2', "type": 'shoe' }       
]
...
computed {
   filteredShoes(){
      let shoes = this.coor.filter(item => item.type === 'shoe');

      ...
      return shoes; // return an array to be looped in HTML
   },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deep computed in array, as bellow

```
  computed: {
    computedArray: {
      cache: false,
      get() {
        return this.sourceArray;
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: not working in array of objects